# ssh_config don't work under ngrok

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openssh

I am trying to connect to my homeserver via ssh under [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), using the default `ssh_config` and default `sshd_config` setting, so i try:

```
ssh -vT localhost
```

Then noticed that the method of authentication that get is:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

So i put the password and works!!

But when i try to connect with ngrok

```
ssh -vT esneyder@0.tcp.ngrok.io
```

got

`debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey`

and fail, even if a set up a public key does not work, for some reason the configuration change when try to connect with a host different to localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it work i had to add the port number the ngrok provide me so, i try:

```
ssh -p 14592 -v esneyder@0.tcp.ngrok.io
```

Then it ask for the password and can login successfully.